# Vertical Alignment issue due to font-family

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am facing an issue of text getting a bit down in a tag vertically. This issue is particular to Open Sans google font. Arial and other fonts seem to be working fine. Don't know whats the issue.

Please find the jsFiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/or7nkyts/3/

First button has Open Sans and 2nd one has Arial font-family.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<a  target="_blank"  href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn testClass">
    <i style="font-size: 24px; color: #fff; vertical-align: middle;" class="fa fa-address-book-o"></i>
    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">Blue Button</span>
</a>
<a  target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial;"  href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn testClass">
    <i style="font-size: 24px; color: #fff; vertical-align: middle;" class="fa fa-address-book-o"></i>
    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">Blue Button</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Try by using center instead middle in style.

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` is correct

Comment: I am using Chrome. But it's an issue across all the browsers I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is because of how the font is made and there is very little you can do about it except manipulate it with css.

If you put a border on the `span` for the button text you will see that the font itself has a greater margin on the top than on the bottom and that it is actually middle aligned to the icon.

```
a.testClass span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is a solution that might work better for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/32cLkm5x/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But issue in my case is that I have this case in a page builder app, where users can set the font-family, font-size, padding, margin and border of the button. Also they can manage the font-size of the icon. So it becomes difficult to add such fixes in general.